# fscanf() not working as I was expecting

Tags: c

This is the code (located inside a function) that opens a file and then reads its content with `fscanf()`:

```
FILE *file = NULL;
int xTemp = 0, xTot = 0;
int yTemp = 0, yTot = 0;
int zTemp = 0, zTot = 0;
int i = 0;

file = fopen(nomeFile, "r");

if(file == NULL) {

    return 0;

} else {

    while(!feof(file)) {

        if(fscanf(file, "%f %f %f", &xTemp, &yTemp, &zTemp) != 3) {

            return -1;

        } else {

            i++;
            xTot += xTemp;
            yTot += yTemp;
            zTot += zTemp;

        }

    }

    coords.x = xTot/i;
    coords.y = yTot/i;
    coords.z = zTot/i;

    return i;

}
```

And this is the content of the file i'm reading using `fscanf()`:

```
3.5 2.1 -1.4
4.1 -4.1 2.9
2.6 2.5 3.2
-1.2 0.0 4.3
1.5 1.3 6.0
```

The problem is that `fscanf()` won't assign to `xTemp`, `yTemp` and `zTemp` the proper values.

Comment: `fscanf()` does work as expected, unless you're using a low quality C library. Maybe just your expectations are not right...

Comment: Of course `fscanf()` was working as it should but i was expecting another result. Thank you :)

Comment: @ShadowBroker Another result? contrary to the thread/post name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float variables instead of `int`s. In `fscanf` you are using `%f` but the variables are ints which invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string specifies 3 `float` values, but you're passing pointers to `int`. You should see a compiler warning about using different types.

If you want to read `float`, then use `float` variables to receive the data.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the variables as `int`,

```
int xTemp = 0, xTot = 0;
int yTemp = 0, yTot = 0;
int zTemp = 0, zTot = 0;
```

but scan them as `float`s, so the values are the bit representation of the `float`s interpreted as `int` (although it is undefined behaviour, so anything else might happen too).

Furthermore, your loop control is wrong,

```
while(!feof(file)) {

    if(fscanf(file, "%f %f %f", &xTemp, &yTemp, &zTemp) != 3) {

        return -1;

    }
```

will always return `-1`. `feof(file)` will only become true *after* you tried to read data from past the end of the file, so the loop will run again after the last line has been read, and then the `fscanf` won't read three values anymore.

A better loop control would be

```
while(fscanf(file, "%f %f %f", &xTemp, &yTemp, &zTemp) == 3)
```